# Grails + PhoneGap: Grails as Controller and Model for Phonegap Application

Tags: cordova, grails, heroku

I am new to web development and the MVC concepts. I want to build a web app for android and iphone using Phonegap. I will be making the view with java script and css; however, I want the interface to communicate with a Grails app that I will deploy somewhere like Heroku. I've built a simple Grails app before, but I don't know how to communicate with things that are outside the Grails framework. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create a RESTful interface using JSON or XML. On the client side you'll be able to use jQuery to pull in the JSON. For the server side, you may want to take a look at the [Grails docs on webservices](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html).